# how to differentiate between normal url and image url programmactically

Tags: python, http, url, web

how to differentiate between normal url and image url(url which have just image).

normal url: http://www.wikipedia.org/
image url: https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTwC6cNpAen5dgGgTmmH2SG75xhvTN-oRliaOgG-3meNQVm-GdpUu7SQX5wpA

Comment: follow the url and read the Content-Type.

Comment: Preferably using HEAD and not GET, if the server is nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a `head` request to check the content type of the `url`. HEAD request will not download the body content. 
Example using python [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module:

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTwC6cNpAen5dgGgTmmH2SG75xhvTN-oRliaOgG-3meNQVm-GdpUu7SQX5wpA"
>>> h = requests.head(url)
>>> print h.headers.get('content-type')
image/jpeg
```

Comment: this requests library is freaking cool. One more reason to start migrating from php to python ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Almost always the HTTP server will return a Content-Type header in the response to a `GET` or `HEAD` url request:

[image]

The quickest thing to do to process a large number of urls would be to retrieve just the headers without downloading the whole file and check for its mime type on the content-type response header (Here is a list of [image mime types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#Type_image) you must check against. They all begin with image/ so that's what you'll be looking for).

For example, using pycurl (you can get it using pip or [here](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/download/) if you are on windows; [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pycurl) for 64 bit windows), something like this will check the response headers (I'm not fluent in python so I suggest you search on how to parse the Content-Type header for a better way to check for image mime types an encapsulate it properly on a function):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pycurl
from StringIO import StringIO
import re

def check_image(url):

    headers = StringIO()

    c = pycurl.Curl()
    c.setopt(c.URL, url)
    c.setopt(c.HEADER, 1)
    c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)
    c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0) # do not verify ssl certificate
    c.setopt(c.NOBODY, 1) # header only, no body
    c.setopt(c.HEADERFUNCTION, headers.write)
    c.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, lambda x: None)
    c.perform()
    c.close()
    a = re.compile("^.*?Content-Type:( )*image/.*?$", re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
    if a.match(headers.getvalue()) is None:
        return False
    else:
        return True

if check_image('http://www.wikipedia.org/') is False:
    print 'The resource in http://www.wikipedia.org/ is not an image'

if check_image('https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTwC6cNpAen5dgGgTmmH2SG75xhvTN-oRliaOgG-3meNQVm-GdpUu7SQX5wpA') is True:
    print 'The resource in https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTwC6cNpAen5dgGgTmmH2SG75xhvTN-oRliaOgG-3meNQVm-GdpUu7SQX5wpA is an image'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the content type of as URL before downloading it, that's what the HTTP command `HEAD` is for. If you do a `HEAD` instead of a `GET`, you will get the same headers that a `GET` would have returned, but without the body (meaning less overhead for you and for the server).

One of those headers should be `Content-Type`, and that will tell you whether it's an image.

If you want to go a little farther, you can guess at the filename from the disposition header and, failing that, the extension of the basename of the final redirected URL, which is what browsers generally do to show you images in cases where the server is broken, but that's rarely needed.

If you can't make any network requests at all for some reason, the best you can do is guess heuristically. If you're only scraping from one particular server, like Wikipedia, you can get a list of URLs and try to find a pattern that server uses--e.g., the `images` in a certain part of the URL--which will probably work for many images, but may not work for all, and may break next time they do a major service upgrade, so you'll have to keep watching and periodically improve your heuristic code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't determine a URL's contents just by looking at the URL.

Your best bet would be to fetch the page and inspect the contents that were retrieved.